# JButton ActionListener performs if- and else- statement

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am trying to program a basic Nine Men's Morris game in Java for school. 
The GUI consists of 24 JButtons. The first Button, that is clicked,  is supposed to set the starting position of a move, the second button the destination. I tried to create a bool and set it to true after a button was clicked once, and check, whether that boolean is true or false to determine, whether the Button should set the start or the destination. 
However, when I tried it like that and printed Start and Dest to the console, they both were set to 0,1,0. I am fairly new to  Java, so there might be quite some bad practice going on right there.

```
    JButton button010 = new JButton("");
    button010.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(!targ) {
                    setStart(0,1,0);
                    targ = true;
                } else {
                    setDest(0,1,0);
                    targ = false;
            }
        }
    });
    button010.setOpaque(false);
    button010.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    button010.setBorderPainted(false);
    button010.setBounds(222, 11, 47, 44);
    contentPane.add(button010);
```

Comment: You will probably want to distill your problem and your code to the smallest bit of code that compiles, runs and demonstrates the problem for us, a [mcve], and then post this mcve here with your question. This will afford us the best chance of fully understanding your problem and your code and then give a decent answer.

Comment: Having said that, you've got some unrelated problems with this code, including hard-coding the start and dest values, and using `setBounds(...)` rather than the Swing layout managers. Both these things can cause problems down the road.

Comment: `button010.setBounds(222, 11, 47, 44);` Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: `they both were set to 0,1,0.` - well you have 23 other buttons. We don't know what ActionLisener does for those buttons. We have no idea what your setStart(...) and setDest(...) methods do. Also why do you call your Boolean variable "targ". I would suggest a better name is "start". Then it would default to true, since that is the first value you are trying to set when you click a button. If conditions are easier to read in the positive, so you would then do `if (start) {...} else {...}`.

Comment: `they both were set to 0,1,0.` - well you have 23 other buttons. We don't know what ActionLisener does for those buttons. We have no idea what your setStart(...) and setDest(...) methods do. So we can't answer your question since the problem is likely in the code you didn't post.

Comment: ..........................hello?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to you question, only a suggestion for a better design to remove the hardcoding in your listener code.

Why do you call your Boolean variable "targ". Since you have "start" and "dest" methods why are you creating a third variable name? I would suggest a better name is "start" so you know it is related to your start/dest methods. It would default to true, since that is the first value you are trying to set when you click a button.

So your custom Action might be something like:

```
class GameAction action = new Action()
{
    private int value1;
    private int value2;
    private int value3;

    public GameAction(int value1, int value2, int value3)
    {
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
        this.value3 = value3;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (start)
        {
            setStart(value1, value2, value3);
            start = false;
        }
        else
        {
            setDest(value1, value2, value3);
            start = true;
        }
 }
```

You would use more appropriate variable names.

Now all your logic is in a single class and if you ever need to change the logic it is contained in one place instead of 24 custom listeners.

Then in your code when you create the button you would do:

```
JButton button010 = new JButton("");
button010.addActionListener( new GameAction(0, 1, 0) );
```

Of course it would be even better to create your 24 buttons in a loop so you don't have to hardcode the parameters.

Comment: As good an answer that can be created given the state of the question 1+

Answer (score 0):

Not a real or full answer since your question is currently incomplete and cannot be answered as currently stated, but I'm testing this code out on how to create a 9 Man's Morris Grid using Swing, using layout managers, and with separation of the model from the GUI. I have created a 7 x 7 grid of JLabel and added it to a JPanel that uses GridLayout(7, 7).  If the grid position matches a cell position in the 9 man's morris, then a grid cell is created, with mouse listener and all. 
 The following code creates this GUI:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MorrisPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int ICON_WIDTH = 80;
    private static final int SMALL_OVAL = 10;
    private static final int LARGE_OVAL = 40;
    private static final int GRID_SIDES = 7;
    private MorrisGameGrid game = new MorrisGameGrid();
    private Map<MorrisCell, JLabel> cellLabelMap = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<JLabel, MorrisCell> labelCellMap = new HashMap<>();
    private Icon blankIcon;
    private Icon cellIcon;
    private Icon whiteIcon;
    private Icon blackIcon;

    public MorrisPanel() {
        blankIcon = createIcon(null, 0);
        cellIcon = createIcon(Color.DARK_GRAY, SMALL_OVAL);
        whiteIcon = createIcon(Color.WHITE, LARGE_OVAL);
        blackIcon = createIcon(Color.DARK_GRAY, LARGE_OVAL);

        setLayout(new GridLayout(GRID_SIDES, GRID_SIDES));
        MyMouse myMouse = new MyMouse();
        List<MorrisColumn> columns = Arrays.asList(MorrisColumn.values());
        Collections.reverse(columns);
        for (MorrisColumn column : columns) {
            for (MorrisRow row : MorrisRow.values()) {
                MorrisCell cell = new MorrisCell(column, row);
                JLabel label = new JLabel(blankIcon);
                if (game.contains(cell)) {
                    label.setIcon(cellIcon);
                    label.addMouseListener(myMouse);
                    cellLabelMap.put(cell, label);
                    labelCellMap.put(label, cell);
                } 
                add(label);
            }
        }
    }

    private Icon createIcon(Color color, int size) {
        int w = ICON_WIDTH;
        int h = ICON_WIDTH;
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        if (color != null) {
            Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2.setColor(color);
            int x = (ICON_WIDTH - size) / 2;
            int y = x;
            int width = size;
            int height = size;
            g2.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.drawOval(x, y, width, height);
            g2.dispose();
        }
        return new ImageIcon(img);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        for (MorrisEdge edge : game.getEdges()) {
            JLabel l1 = cellLabelMap.get(edge.getCell1());
            JLabel l2 = cellLabelMap.get(edge.getCell2());
            int x1 = l1.getLocation().x + l1.getWidth() / 2;
            int x2 = l2.getLocation().x + l2.getWidth() / 2;
            int y1 = l1.getLocation().y + l1.getHeight() / 2;
            int y2 = l2.getLocation().y + l2.getHeight() / 2;
            g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        }
    }

    private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            JLabel source = (JLabel) e.getSource();
            MorrisCell cell = labelCellMap.get(source);


            // TODO: Begin testing block -- delete this
            System.out.println(cell); // !! just for testing purposes
            Icon icon = source.getIcon();
            if (icon == cellIcon) {
                source.setIcon(blackIcon);
            } else if (icon == blackIcon) {
                source.setIcon(whiteIcon);
            } else if (icon == whiteIcon) {
                source.setIcon(cellIcon);
            }
            // TODO: end testing block

            // TODO: finish
        }

    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        MorrisPanel mainPanel = new MorrisPanel();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestButtons");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
class MorrisGame {
    private MorrisGameGrid grid = new MorrisGameGrid();

    // TODO: logic for game goes here

    public MorrisGameGrid getGrid() {
        return grid;
    }
}
```

```
class MorrisGameGrid {
    Set<MorrisCell> cells = new HashSet<>();
    Set<MorrisEdge> edges = new HashSet<>();

    public MorrisGameGrid() {
        cells.add(new MorrisCell("a1"));
        cells.add(new MorrisCell("d1"));
        cells.add(new MorrisCell("g1"));
        cells.add(new MorrisCell("b2"));
        cells.add(new MorrisCell("d2"));
        cells.add(new MorrisCell("f2"));
        cells.add(new MorrisCell("c3"));
        cells.add(new MorrisCell("d3"));
        cells.add(new MorrisCell("e3"));
        cells.add(new MorrisCell("a4"));
        cells.add(new MorrisCell("b4"));
        cells.add(new MorrisCell("c4"));
        cells.add(new MorrisCell("e4"));
        cells.add(new MorrisCell("f4"));
        cells.add(new MorrisCell("g4"));
        cells.add(new MorrisCell("c5"));
        cells.add(new MorrisCell("d5"));
        cells.add(new MorrisCell("e5"));
        cells.add(new MorrisCell("b6"));
        cells.add(new MorrisCell("d6"));
        cells.add(new MorrisCell("f6"));
        cells.add(new MorrisCell("a7"));
        cells.add(new MorrisCell("d7"));
        cells.add(new MorrisCell("g7"));

        connectLoop(getCell("a1"), getCell("d1"), getCell("g1"), 
                getCell("g4"), getCell("g7"), getCell("d7"),
                getCell("a7"), getCell("a4"));
        connectLoop(getCell("b2"), getCell("d2"), getCell("f2"),
                getCell("f4"), getCell("f6"), getCell("d6"), 
                getCell("b6"), getCell("b4"));
        connectLoop(getCell("c3"), getCell("d3"), getCell("e3"),
                getCell("e4"), getCell("e5"), getCell("d5"), 
                getCell("c5"), getCell("c4"));
        connectEdge(getCell("d1"), getCell("d2"), getCell("d3"));
        connectEdge(getCell("d7"), getCell("d6"), getCell("d5"));
        connectEdge(getCell("a4"), getCell("b4"), getCell("c4"));
        connectEdge(getCell("e4"), getCell("f4"), getCell("g4"));

    }

    public boolean contains(MorrisCell cell) {
        return cells.contains(cell);
    }

    public Set<MorrisCell> getCells() {
        return cells;
    }

    public Set<MorrisEdge> getEdges() {
        return edges;
    }

    private void connectCells(MorrisCell cell1, MorrisCell cell2) {
        cell1.addNeighbors(cell2);
        cell2.addNeighbors(cell1);
        edges.add(new MorrisEdge(cell1, cell2));
    }

    private void connectEdge(MorrisCell... cells) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cells.length - 1; i++) {
            connectCells(cells[i], cells[i + 1]);
        }
    }

    private void connectLoop(MorrisCell... cells) {
        connectEdge(cells);
        connectCells(cells[0], cells[cells.length - 1]);
    }

    public MorrisCell getCell(String text) {
        if (text == null || text.length() != 2) {
            String errorTxt = "For text: " + text;
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(errorTxt);
        }
        MorrisCell temp = new MorrisCell(text);
        for (MorrisCell morrisCell : cells) {
            if (morrisCell.equals(temp)) {
                return morrisCell;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
class MorrisEdge {
    private MorrisCell cell1;
    private MorrisCell cell2;

    public MorrisEdge(MorrisCell cell1, MorrisCell cell2) {
        if (cell1.compareTo(cell2) < 0) {
            this.cell1 = cell1;
            this.cell2 = cell2;
        } else {
            this.cell2 = cell1;
            this.cell1 = cell2;
        }
    }

    public MorrisCell getCell1() {
        return cell1;
    }

    public MorrisCell getCell2() {
        return cell2;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = ((cell1 == null) ? 0 : cell1.hashCode());
        result += ((cell2 == null) ? 0 : cell2.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        MorrisEdge other = (MorrisEdge) obj;

        boolean e1 = compareCells(cell1, other.cell1);
        e1 &= compareCells(cell2, other.cell2);
        boolean e2 = compareCells(cell1, other.cell2);
        e2 &= compareCells(cell2, other.cell1);
        return e1 || e2;
    }

    private static boolean compareCells(MorrisCell c1, MorrisCell c2) {
        if (c1 == null) {
            if (c2 != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!c1.equals(c2))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Edge [" + cell1 + ", " + cell2 + "]";
    }

}
```

```
class MorrisCell implements Comparable<MorrisCell> {
    private MorrisColumn column;
    private MorrisRow row;
    private Set<MorrisCell> neighbors = new HashSet<>();
    private MorrisPlayer player = null;

    public MorrisCell(MorrisColumn column, MorrisRow row) {
        this.column = column;
        this.row = row;
    }

    public MorrisCell(String text) {
        if (text.length() != 2) {
            String errorTxt = "For text: " + text;
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(errorTxt);
        }
        String columnTxt = text.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase();
        String rowTxt = text.substring(1, 2);
        MorrisColumn column1 = null;
        MorrisRow row1 = null;
        for (MorrisColumn c : MorrisColumn.values()) {
            if (c.getText().equals(columnTxt)) {
                column1 = c;
                break;
            }
        }
        for (MorrisRow r : MorrisRow.values()) {
            if (r.getText().equals(rowTxt)) {
                row1 = r;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (column1 == null || row1 == null) {
            String errorTxt = "For text: " + text;
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(errorTxt);
        }
        this.column = column1;
        this.row = row1;
    }

    public void addNeighbors(MorrisCell neighbor) {
        neighbors.add(neighbor);
    }

    public boolean isNeighbor(MorrisCell possibleNeighbor) {
        return neighbors.contains(possibleNeighbor);
    }

    public MorrisRow getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    public MorrisColumn getColumn() {
        return column;
    }

    public void setPlayer(MorrisPlayer player) {
        this.player = player;
    }

    public MorrisPlayer getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((column == null) ? 0 : column.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((row == null) ? 0 : row.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        MorrisCell other = (MorrisCell) obj;
        if (column != other.column)
            return false;
        if (row != other.row)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return column.getText() + row.getText();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MorrisCell o) {
        int colCompare = column.compareTo(o.column);
        int rowCompare = row.compareTo(o.row);
        return colCompare != 0 ? colCompare : rowCompare;
    }

}
```

```
enum MorrisRow {
    ONE("1"), TWO("2"), THREE("3"), FOUR("4"), FIVE("5"), SIX("6"), SEVEN("7");

    private String text;

    private MorrisRow(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

```
enum MorrisColumn {
    A("a"), B("b"), C("c"), D("d"), E("e"), F("f"), G("g");

    private String text;

    private MorrisColumn(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

```
enum MorrisPlayer {
    WHITE("White"), BLACK("Black");

    private String text;

    private MorrisPlayer(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

}
```

Comment: (1+) Cool, I had no idea what a Nine Men's Morris game was.

Comment: @camickr: me neither, and so I had to go to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine_men%27s_morris) for the details.